# Focus only one time - Jquery

Tags: jquery, focus, lost-focus

hi friends i have a textarea and i want to use `animate()` and `css()` functions with this element.

`css()` function is working properly but the problem is `focus()` func. After page load everything is fine,

when i focus to textarea its height is incrementing 50px but when I blur and then focus again to textarea then height incrementing 50px again.

I don't want to use `blur()` function.

My question is about using `focus()` function. I want to use `focus()`  one time per page load.

```
<script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#sharePost").focus(function(){
                  $(this).animate({height:"+=50px"});
                  $(this).css("background-color","#ffccdd");
                  });
                  $("#sharePost").blur(function(){
                  //$(this).animate({height:"-=50px"});
                  });
              });
</script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fire an event just once, you can use the [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function, which attaches an event listener then removes it after the first time it's fired:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sharePost").one('focus', function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"+=50px"});
        $(this).css("background-color","#ffccdd");
    });

});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qS4Fz/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this using [jQuery's .one() function](http://api.jquery.com/one/). This only fires the event handler at most once for the element that it is attached to.

You would not need to use `$(document).ready(function()...` in this case (unless your script comes *before* your #sharePost element). As an example for you could just do:

```
$("#sharePost").one("focus", function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"+=50px"});
    $(this).css("background-color","#ffccdd");
});
```

After the first `focus` on the element, the handler containing your .animate and .css will never run again. You can go from there if you are wanting is to shrink back down when focus leaves the element.